# Frequently re-importing modules

Tags: powershell

I am rather new to powershell, and wrote a few modules and have some scripts that rely on these modules. I find myself removing and reloading the modules constantly because I have to change my modules slightly.

Am I doing something wrong or is this really how microsoft intended developers to work with modules?

Or should I simply have my script start with rmo -Name  ipmo -Name ? (that feels a bit weird to me, but maybe it shouldn't).

The only thing I found so far is a handy way to reload a module (ok, that helps, but still...).

Is there an easier way I just don't know about?

Comment: How often are you doing this? I would have thought module are for relatively completed code sets. If you are still developing them perhaps use more functions you can reinitialize easily until they are ready? Also you can just use `import-module -name modname -force` so save a step. I'm pretty sure there are other approaches.

Comment: Maybe I am following the wrong approach. I am building it all hand in hand. Writing scripts to configure PCs that are going into our machines we build. There is a lot of commonality in the different scripts, these commonalities I write in modules. They are rather small, so it's not impossible this way, but indeed, I am reloading scripts pretty often. The -Force command will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ipmo X -Force`. It works for me, I use it quite often. `ipmo` is, of course, an alias for `Import-Module`